# CSS 100% - 200px?

Tags: css, width, positioning, spacing

I'm trying to use `<div>` objects and CSS to emulate the appearance of frames for a project that I'm working on. Using the following code I was able to properly stretch the list on the left with a `border-right`, `padding`, and (if I choose) a `background` using only one extra element:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-content">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- more content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
}

#sidebar-content {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This worked well until I tried adding another element at the top of the content which stretched horizontally. Here's the current code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="criteria">
        <!-- select boxes -->
    </div>
    <!-- other content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#criteria {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #FF9;
}
```

This picture shows the results

[image: Results of the above CSS and HTML]

I tried adding the following rule:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

although this stretched the `#content` div to the width of the body element, not the body minus the sidebar - so the content appeared below the fold (and beneath the sidebar on the left)

How can I use CSS to stretch the criteria box to fill the content area horizontally?

EDIT -

I wanted to upload a picture of what happened after Karl's recommendation:

> Remove the `float: left` from `#content`. If there is a floated element next to a normal block element, the block element will fill the remaining space. Also don't set the width attribute.

Here's what happened when `float: left` was removed

[image: Results of the above recommended fix]

Close, however now the `#criteria` is stretching to cover up the sidebar. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from `#content`. If there is a floated element next to a normal block element, the block element will fill the remaining space. Also don't set the width attribute.

---

**Edit:**

To address the issue of `#criteria` which is absolutely-positioned forcing itself over to the left, you can add a left-margin to `#content` to account for the width of the sidebar, as Steven discovered.

As a random sidenote, this would also allow you to keep the content aligned in the case that the sidebar did not take 100% height like it does in Steven's example.

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot of what happened after your proposed solution. As you can see, it sort of worked - but not perfectly. With `#sidebar` floating and `#content` not, the sidebar actually floats on top of content, so content's width is 200px greater than you would hope.

Comment: Shortly after updating the question the answer came to me, with help from your solution. With the content block stretching over the sidebar I applied `margin-left: 200px` to `#content` and that was that. If you adjust your answer accordingly then I can accept it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m5XLB/ What i cant quite understand is, that it's working fine in this fiddle it's not overlaying to the left & that's without your proposed 200px margin fix, and out of curiosity why do you need it absolute positioned ?

Comment: It's likely a side effect of `#criteria` being absolutely positioned with `left: 0`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Xavier: Your fiddle isn't doing it cause the `#content` div in your fiddle still has the original CSS properties (floated and position relative)

Comment: @Xavier: To answer your question, I needed `#criteria` absolutely positioned so that it would stretch to fill the screen horizontally

Comment: You just made my day!
I had been searching for solution for about two hours and thanx tu you i found it. THNX A LOT

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this before to get a sidebar layout

**sidebar css**

width: 200px;
    z-index:2;
    float: left;

**content css**

margin-left: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 2

You can use a similar technique to get a header `<div>` too.

I might not have got the css exactly correct, but the idea is to use a combination of margin, padding and z-index to get a frames-like effect.

Comment: sorry about the css for,atting, my ipad is a real PITA to type on!

Answer (score 0):

One option would just to have the sidebar and content areas' width based on percentage... say 20% for the sidebar and 80% for the content. I've run into this problem before and just gone with that, but I didn't do too much research on it.

Comment: While that would work, it doesn't meet my initial criteria: I wish to emulate frames. use a common applications which uses frames (such as phpMyAdmin) and you'll notice the sidebar never changes as you change the size of the window. Furthermore, I'd eventually like to apply a background image to the sidebar so I really need to keep the pixel dimensions exact.